# LibreOffice Writer auto numbering in different header levels

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I've been using Ms Word for a while now and decided to try the open source LibreOffice Writer. Unfortunately, I'm having a problem to create auto numbering for each header. It's easy to do this in Ms Word as there is dedicated button on the top, however none of the shortcut button in LibreOffice Writer works like Ms Word.

**Desired Output**

```
1. Header 1
   1.1. Header 2
   1.2. Header 2
      1.2.1. Header 3
      1.2.2. Header 3
   1.3. Header 2
2. Header 1
3. Header 1
4. Header 1
```

Answer (score 2):

#### I'm having problems ceating auto numbering for each header.

There is a dedicated dialog "Chapter Numbering" which allows you to configure your preferred settings. You can even "load/save" your settings.

1. Go to "Tools" > "Chapter Numbering"
2. To achieve your desired numbering scheme simply select Levels 1, 2 and 3 in turn.

   For each level set "Number" to "1, 2, 3...".

   The right of the dialog will show an example of how it will look when applied.
3. Click "OK" and start writing.

[image]

<sup>Instructions for Version: 6.2.1.2 (x64)</sup>